# Selection Criteria in DB2 database for XML data type

Tags: xml, database, db2

I am trying to select the data using selection criteria from XML data type column in DB2 database.

The below query works in oracle

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME where extractvalue(xmlcolumn,'/row/c2') LIKE '84%'
```

In MSSQL below select query works

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME where xmlcolumn.value('(/row/c2)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') LIKE '84%'
```

Please suggest the same to achieve in DB2 database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with tablename (id, xmlcolumn) as (
select *
from table(values 
  (1, xmlparse(document '
<row>
  <c2>84123</c2>
</row>
'))
, (2, xmlparse(document '
<row>
  <c2>85123</c2>
</row>
'))
))
select *
from tablename
where xmlexists('$x/row[fn:starts-with(c2, "84")]' passing xmlcolumn as "x")
;
```